# I'm learning multidimensional arrays and trying to write them out with for. I found it, but I don't understand how it works

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

so I'm learning Java nad now I'm on multidimensional arrays. I think I understand how they work. And I found how to write them out with for, but the whing is what happens with for and why we need two for's. This is the code:

```
int[][] myNumbers = { {1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7} };

for (int i = 0; i < myNumbers.length; i++) {

    for (int j = 0; j < myNumbers[i].length; j++) {

        System.out.println(myNumbers[i][j]);

    }
}
```

Comment: The first outer for loop to loop through the rows of the array, and the inner loop to loop through each item in a row

Comment: Change to `System.out.println("myNumbers[" + i + "][" + j + "] =" + myNumbers[i][j]);` to get a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to change *i* and *j* variable names this way:

```
int[][] myNumbers = { {1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7} };

for (int row = 0; row < myNumbers.length; row++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < myNumbers[row].length; column++) {
        System.out.println(myNumbers[row][column]);
    }
}
```

When you have a 2d array, you have first an array that represents rows and each row will have another array that represents columns for the current row.

Given your example, it would look like this:

```
myNumbers[0] is the row 0 of your 2d array, its value is an array => [1, 2, 3, 4]
myNumbers[1] is the row 1 of your 2d array, its value is an array => [5, 6, 7]
```

in the first *for* you are iterating through rows, while in the second *for* you are iterating through the columns of that row.

```
myNumber[0][1] is the value for the row 0 and column 1, that is 2
myNumber[1][0] is the value for the row 1 and column 0, that is 5
```

The output will then be:

```
myNumber[0][0] => 1
myNumber[0][1] => 2
myNumber[0][2] => 3
myNumber[0][3] => 4
myNumber[1][0] => 5
myNumber[1][1] => 6
myNumber[1][2] => 7
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, you are completly right with your answer. But I think it always helps to show the concrete outcome of some code.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. @Mafick

Answer (score 0):

Well the first for-loop will be selecting one of the two arrays, the second for-loop loops through the array content.

first array = {1, 2, 3, 4}

second array = {5, 6, 7}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `i` and `j` trying use `row` and `col` respectively, that should help you understand the necessity of the two for loops for iterating over the rows and columns of your 2-dimensional array `myNumbers` separately:

```
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] myNumbers = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, 
                         {5, 6, 7}};
    for (int row = 0; row < myNumbers.length; row++) {
      for (int col = 0; col < myNumbers[row].length; col++) {
        System.out.println(String.format("myNumbers[%d][%d] = %d", row, col, myNumbers[row][col]));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output**:

```
myNumbers[0][0] = 1
myNumbers[0][1] = 2
myNumbers[0][2] = 3
myNumbers[0][3] = 4
myNumbers[1][0] = 5
myNumbers[1][1] = 6
myNumbers[1][2] = 7
```